# Unknown property this.attrs. It is not defined on tag xp:inputText

Tags: xpages

I am quite new to XPages. To start with I have downloaded some sample Bootstrap-xpage applications. The application which I am exploring doesn't depend on extension library.

For below line of code it throws error "*Unknown property this.attrs. It is not defined on tag xp:inputText*"

```
<xp:this.facets>
  <xp:panel xp:key="facet_1">
    <xp:inputText id="inputSenderName" value="#{mycard.sendername}" required="true">
      <xp:this.attrs>
        <xp:attr name="placeholder" value="Your Name" />
      </xp:this.attrs>
      <xp:this.validators>
        <xp:validateRequired message="Enter your name"></xp:validateRequired>   
      </xp:this.validators>
    </xp:inputText>
  </xp:panel>
</xp:this.facets>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using a domino version < 8.5.3?

Comment: Release 8.5.3CD4 
Revision 20110309.1448-CD4 (Build V853_CD4_03082011) 
Standard Configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by upgrading Domino Designer and Domino to a version which is not a beta release. 8.5.3 CD4 was one of the beta releases before 8.5.3 was officially released.

The latest version of IBM Domino is 9.0.1.

The `attrs` property was introduced in 8.5.3 as you can see from this answer: [ReadOnly field in Xpage not submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637693/readonly-field-in-xpage-not-submitted/14642466#14642466)